# Error in TCPDF while generating

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Am using TCPDF and I have an error while generating the PDF file it says
TCPDF ERROR: Not a JPEG file: ...Am inserting an jpg IMAGE  but not able to download ..Can any one please help the JPEG which am trying download its opening fine when opened manually..The path is correct

Answer (score 1):

it's code check types in  TCPDF

```
$a = getimagesize($file);
if (empty($a)) {
    $this->Error('Missing or incorrect image file: '.$file);
}
if ($a[2] != 2) {
    $this->Error('Not a JPEG file: '.$file);
}
```

check $a[2] value
run code

```
$a = getimagesize('path to image');
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image has a JPG extension but it is not a JPEG type image.
Try to open it with an image editor like GIMP and save it with the correct format.